# Jsoup: Android App crashes

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I have this following code:

```
String webPage = "http://www.something.com";
String html = null;

try{
      html = Jsoup.connect(webPage).get().html();
} catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
Toast.makeText(this, html, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If its the Exception `Exception` the code does the other stuff (before this code) and does not do the code in `try{}`, if the Exception is `IOException`, the app crashes

Comment: Post the exception. My guess is that connect() or get() or html() failed. Break down that line. It is easier to debug

Comment: Clarify your explanation, where does the exception occur?

Comment: do you want to read the LogCat text?

Comment: Not this time is the problem has been solved. But in general, It is hard to help with little info

Answer (score 0):

Also, you should read what kind of Exception Jsoup can throw and handle each of them as you plan to instead of catching the base jave Exception class. You can also catch multiple exceptions in one catch block if you plan to handle them the same way.

Example:

```
String webPage = "http://www.something.com";
String html = null;
try {
    html = Jsoup.connect(webPage).get().html();
} catch (SocketTimeoutException|IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
Toast.makeText(this, html, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense and won't even compile. `Exception` will catch any sub-classes as well; `IOException` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The app crashes due to [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

You are not allowed to perform network operations from the main thread.

Instead, try running `Jsoup` from an [AsyncTask](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/)

Comment: tried that too, but as soon as it is something with IOException, it crashes

Comment: Mark the question complete if you've found a solution!